# C# Custom Setter Entity Framework 6.1.3

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I've tried searching for an answer to this question but maybe my google skills are slacking (it is Wednesday after all).

I want to use a custom setter like this.

```
public class ITEMViewModel
{
    public ITEM_ACTIVE ITEMDATA { get; set; }
    private string _ThumbnailUNC;
    public string ThumbnailUNC
    {
        get
        {
            return _ThumbnailUNC;
        }
        set
        {
            _ThumbnailUNC = FileLocation.getThumb(value);
        }
    }
}
```

That works great as long as I do something like this.

```
    ae.ITEM_ACTIVE
         .Where(x => x.ORG == Org && x.PART_NUMBER == PN)
         .Select(x => new ITEMViewModel
         {
              ITEMDATA = x,
              ThumbnailUNC = x.PART_NUMBER //This is the important part
         })
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

What I want to do is this.

```
set
{
   _ThumbnailUNC = FileLocation.getThumb(ITEMDATA.PART_NUMBER); //Not value
}

ae.ITEM_ACTIVE
         .Where(x => x.ORG == Org && x.PART_NUMBER == PN)
         .Select(x => new ITEMViewModel
         {
              ITEMDATA = x
         })
         .FirstOrDefault();
```

The second way always returns null (It's never setting?) Is there any way to always have that setter run when I populate ITEMDATA?

I'm fairly new to custom setters and getters so any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it on the wrong property.

```
private ITEM_ACTIVE _itemData;
public string ThumbnailUNC { get; private set; }
public ITEM_ACTIVE ITEMDATA 
{ 
    get 
    {
        return _itemData;
    }
    set
    {
        _itemData = value;
        ThumbnailUNC = value.PART_NUMBER;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is exactly what I was looking for! Some times the simple things are hard to google search for :)